# How to ignore certificate verification

Tags: angular

When I execute a request from the server to receive data, I get a certificate error.

```
GET https://ip:5001/api/cards/online net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

And to fix this, I decided to ignore certificate verification. But how to do that? Please give a hint.

Comment: you should at least specify your stack, nodejs/dotnet/php/whatever

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your question on how to ignore certificate verification, this depends on the client you are using to send this request. For example, if you are using [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se), you can add the flag -k to the command. In case you are using Postman, you can advise this [StackOverFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100271/how-to-turn-off-all-ssl-checks-for-postman-for-a-specific-site)