# Express JS https api can't be reached

Tags: node.js, express, https, ssl-certificate

I'm updating a node.js api with Express js from http to https. This is hosted on AWS, and is accessed through its ip address, not a webdomain.

I've followed the Express documentation, and created self-signed certificates using `sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ./selfsigned.key -out selfsigned.cert`

However my application is not able to reach the server using https, whereas it worked with http. These are the errors I get:

- Application response: Certificate required
- Postman response: Connection Refused
- Powershell response: Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Could the issue be that the certificates are self-signed? My code is below

```
let fs = require("fs");
let https = require('https');

const crypto = require('crypto')
let express = require('express');
let expressRateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
let mysql = require('mysql');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let winston = require('winston');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');

let key = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/selfsigned.key');
let cert = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/selfsigned.crt');
let credentials = {key: key, cert: cert};

let app = express();
app.set('trust proxy', '127.0.0.1');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//App config

let httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
let httpsPort = 443;

httpsServer.listen(httpsPort, function() {
   console.log("Started codeRedeem https REST API on port " + httpsPort);
});
```

Comment: does this answer your question [How to turn off all SSL checks on Postman for a specific site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100271/how-to-turn-off-all-ssl-checks-on-postman-for-a-specific-site)

Comment: What you would want to do is to create a ca ( crt and key ) and from that ca create the key and cert for your app so from the caller side you can trust the cert that the app  will send, based on the ca.crt you generated first.

Comment: @eekinci apparently that setting was already turned off, turning it on gives an error that the certificate is self-signed. It seems I'll have to take the ca creation approach adam suggested