# How to set Postman Settings to mimic the effect the -k option of curl

Tags: curl, postman

I have been using curl on Linux for a while, and I am beginning to learn to use Postman on Mac Sonoma. I can run curl this way:
$ curl -k https://server_name.xyz.com:10101/hello
And see that server return 200 OK.
(And I can also do curl -v -k to dump out more info)

Now when run Postman:
GET https://server_name.xyz.com:10101/hello
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Is there a quick way to mimic -k option of curl to skip the certificate check?
Also Postman console log shows some info, but does not seem to be at the same level as curl -v. Is there any way to mimic the -v option too?

Thanks!

Postman setting that can run GET command above without error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off all SSL checks on Postman for a specific site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100271/how-to-turn-off-all-ssl-checks-on-postman-for-a-specific-site)